# wordpress twig and gravity form

Tags: php, wordpress, twig, gravityforms

I need to put into my twig template file, in wordpress, a shortcode about my gravityform.

I read [this](https://github.com/timber/timber/wiki/WP-Integration#shortcodes) and I've coded following lines

```
{% filter shortcodes %}
    [gravityform id="1" title="false" description="false"][/gravityform]
{% endfilter %}
```

Now I see all raw html output and not my form in home page. There is any way to process gravity form short code with twig?

Thanks